# Unable to receive notification using ionic-native geofence when i reached in a fence

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, geofencing

First I initialise geofence in constructor and after successfully initialisation I create a geofence with the help of following code...

```
 geofence.initialize().then(() =>{
            alert('Geofence Plugin Ready')
            this.addGeofence()
          },(err) => {
            alert(err)
          }) 

    addGeofence(){
    let fence = [
      {
        id: 'enter',
        latitude: 28.6016271,
        longitude: 77.3519364,
        radius: 1000,
        transitionType: 1,
        notification: {
          id: 1,
          title: 'You crossed a fence',
          text: 'You just arrived at ABC Pvt. Ltd.',
          openAppOnClick: true
        }
      }  ]
    this.geofence.addOrUpdate(fence).then(
      () => console.log('Geofence added'),
     (err) => console.log('Geofence failed to add')
    )

    this.geofence.getWatched().then(
      (res) => console.log('Geofence Watching  ::' + res),
      (err) => console.log('Geofence Error is  :  ' + err)
    )

    this.geofence.onTransitionReceived().subscribe((resp) => {
      console.log("geofence on transition received", resp);
    },(err) =>{
      alert('error'+err)
    })
  }
```

In this code I create a fence in which latitude is 28.6016271 and longitude is 77.3519364, radius of fence is 1000m. According to document of ionic-native geofence when I enter in this fence onTransitionReceived() method called and notify me with text "You just arrived at ABC Pvt. Ltd." either my application is in background or foreground, but currently I am not getting  notification when I entered in this fence.